# Creating 50+ country plots using loops in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I need help using loops in R. I have a data set of 52 countries. I need to create 6 plots for each country. The code is standard across all countries, varying in country_name; start_year; end_year. The data is coming from two sources- 1/ raw_country (pulled from wdi) and raw_gvt_total_spend (imported from IMF) Sample code is below:

```
#INDIA: PLOTS-----
#1. OOP
c1_title <- expression(paste(bold("India"), ":OOP Spending (2001-12)"))
                               
india_p1 <- ggplot(data = raw_in)+
  geom_line(aes(y = SH.XPD.OOPC.CH.ZS, x = year), color = "dark blue")+
  labs(title= c1_title, 
       x = "", 
       y = "% health expenditure")+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
  #ylim(50, 85)+
  #annotate("text", x = 2009, y = 60, label = "Out-of-Pocket Expenses", color = "orange", size = 2.5) +
  ggsave("data/output/graphs/v2/india_p1.pdf", height = 3, width = 5)

#2. GVT SPENDING AS % OF GDP
india_gvt_total_spend <- raw_gvt_total_spend %>%
  filter(country== "India")

india_p2 <- ggplot(data = india_gvt_total_spend)+
  geom_line(aes(y= Value, x = Year), color = "dark blue")+
  labs(title = "Government Spending (2001-12)",
       x = "", 
       y = "% gdp")+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
  #ylim(15, 40)+
  #annotate("text", x = 2009, y = 20, label = "Government spending", color = "dark blue", size = 2.5) +
  ggsave("data/output/graphs/v2/india_p2.pdf", height = 3, width = 5)

#3. GVT HEALTH EXPENDITURE (% CURRENT HEALTH EXPENDITURE)
india_p3 <- ggplot(data = raw_in)+
  geom_line(aes(y = SH.XPD.GHED.CH.ZS, x = year), color = "dark blue")+
  labs(title = "Government Health Spending (2001-12)",
       x = "", 
       y = "% health expenditure")+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
  #ylim(5,40)+
  #annotate("text", x = 2009, y = 20, label = "Government spending", color = "dark blue", size = 2.5)+
  ggsave("data/output/graphs/v2/india_p3.pdf", height = 3, width = 5)

#4. GVT HEALTH EXPENDITURE (% TOTAL PUBLIC EXPENDITURE)
india_p4 <- ggplot(data = raw_in)+
  geom_line(aes(y = SH.XPD.GHED.GE.ZS, x = year), color = "dark blue")+
  labs(title = "Budget Prioritization of Health (2001-12)",
       x = "", 
       y = "% government expenditure")+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
  #ylim(0, 10)+
  ggsave("data/output/graphs/v2/india_p4.pdf", height = 3, width = 5)

#5. EXTERNAL HEALTH SPENDING 
india_p5 <- ggplot(data = raw_in)+
  geom_line(aes(y = SH.XPD.EHEX.CH.ZS, x = year), color = "dark blue")+
  labs(title = "External Health Spending (2001-12)",
       x = "", 
       y = "% health expenditure")+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
  #ylim(0, 10)+
  #annotate("text", x = 2009, y = 5, label = "External Health Expenditure", color = "hot pink", size = 2.5) +
  ggsave("data/output/graphs/v2/india_p5.pdf", height = 3, width = 5)

#6. GDP GROWTH 
india_p6 <- ggplot(data = raw_in)+
  geom_line(aes(y = NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG, x = year), color = "dark blue")+
  labs(title = "Annual GDP Growth (6.5%) (2001-12)",
       x = "", 
       y = "%")+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
  #ylim(0, 20)+
  #annotate("text", x = 2009, y = 20, label = "Government spending", color = "dark blue", size = 2.5) +
  ggsave("data/output/graphs/v2/india_p6.pdf", height = 3, width = 5)

#INDIA: COMBINE PLOTS 
india_combined<- plot_grid(india_p1, india_p3, 
                           india_p4, india_p5,
                           india_p2,india_p6,
                           ncol= 2, nrow=3, tags= "x")

ggsave(filename="data/output/graphs/v2/india_combined.pdf", plot = india_combined, height = 7, width = 7)
```

What's the best way to do this for across all 52 countries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `sapply()`. For example,  for the second kind of plots `GVT SPENDING AS % OF GDP`:

```
required_countries <-c ("United States", "India",.....)

sapply(required_countries, FUN=function(x){
  india_gvt_total_spend <- raw_gvt_total_spend %>%
    filter(country== x)
  title_preformatted <- paste0("Government Spending for",x, "(2001-12)")
  
  x_p2 <- ggplot(data = india_gvt_total_spend)+
    geom_line(aes(y= Value, x = Year), color = "dark blue")+
    labs(title = title_preformatted,
         x = "", 
         y = "% gdp")+
    theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
          axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
    #ylim(15, 40)+
    #annotate("text", x = 2009, y = 20, label = "Government spending", color = "dark blue", size = 2.5) +
    ggsave(path_preformatted, height = 3, width = 5)
}
)
```

If you really want to do this with a for loop, you can iterate over the `required_countries` vector:

```
required_countries <-c ("United States", "India",.....)

for (i in 1:length(required_countries)){
  india_gvt_total_spend <- raw_gvt_total_spend %>%
    filter(country== required_countries[i])
  title_preformatted <- paste0("Government Spending for",required_countries[i]), "(2001-12)")
  path_preformatted <- paste0("data/output/graphs/v2/",required_countries[i]),"_p2.pdf")
  path_preformatted <- gsub(" ","", path_preformatted) #strip white space - e.g. "United States" -> "UnitedStates"
  
  x_p2 <- ggplot(data = india_gvt_total_spend)+
    geom_line(aes(y= Value, x = Year), color = "dark blue")+
    labs(title = title_preformatted,
         x = "", 
         y = "% gdp")+
    theme(axis.title=element_text(size=9),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
          axis.text = element_text(size=7), 
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 6))+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2001, to = 2012, by=2))+
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2001, 2012))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))+
    #ylim(15, 40)+
    #annotate("text", x = 2009, y = 20, label = "Government spending", color = "dark blue", size = 2.5) +
    ggsave(path_preformatted, height = 3, width = 5)
}
```

If you do not want to manually type in all country names, find the unique values in the set of countries you wish to plot for:

```
required_countries <- unique(dataset$countries)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful! The only problem is I have three variables that differ across plots: 1. country_name, 2. start_date and 3. end date. While I can use the required_countries vector how do I solve for different start and end dates?